# SQLDB Java Sample code doesn't work

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud, sqldb

Hi I'm new in Bluemix and I just tried some of sample code of SQLDB in Bluemix.

I tried example from [this site](https://hub.jazz.net/project/pvanrun/SQLDBJava/overview#https://hub.jazz.net/project/pvanrun/SQLDBJava/pvanrun%2520%257C%2520SQLDBJava/_vEGWMOUMEeOAZfbcVnb3zg/_vELOsOUMEeOAZfbcVnb3zg).

I follow the step from readme.md file. But after I deployed my application, error happens.

```
Executing: CREATE SCHEMA SQLDBSAMPLE
Error creating schema: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-552, SQLSTATE=42502, SQLERRMC=USER12999;CREATE SCHEMA, DRIVER=3.66.46
Executing: CREATE TABLE SQLDBSAMPLE.PAYROLL1451703603548 (NAME VARCHAR(20), AGE INTEGER)
Error creating table: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-552, SQLSTATE=42502, SQLERRMC=USER12999;IMPLICIT CREATE SCHEMA, DRIVER=3.66.46
Executing: INSERT INTO SQLDBSAMPLE.PAYROLL1451703603548 VALUES ('John Smith', 52)
Error executing:INSERT INTO SQLDBSAMPLE.PAYROLL1451703603548 VALUES ('John Smith', 52)
SQL Exception: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=SQLDBSAMPLE.PAYROLL1451703603548, DRIVER=3.66.46
Executing: DROP TABLE SQLDBSAMPLE.PAYROLL1451703603548
Error dropping table: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=SQLDBSAMPLE.PAYROLL1451703603548, DRIVER=3.66.46
Executing: DROP SCHEMA SQLDBSAMPLE RESTRICT
Error Dropping schema: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=SQLDBSAMPLE, DRIVER=3.66.46
Finished
```

Comment: Please help guys
I already browse for 3 days only for run simple query in my Java web apps in Bluemix. And still stuck now :(

Comment: "DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-552", through just Googling, indicates you have insufficient permissions. Are you sure you've bound the service to your application and are reading and using the credentials correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The first error you are getting depends on the fact that the user (USER12999) has not the privileges  to create a schema. The second one is related to the same issue, since it is trying to create implicitly the schema. All the next errors are telling you that the table doesn't exist. I guess you're using the free BETA SQL DB Plan. It provides you the default schema (with the same name of your username): you could create the table in that default schema, just commenting out the `CREATE SCHEMA` line and removing explicit schema `SQLDBSAMPLE` from other statements in the sample code you posted.